# slide the finger from right to left, or vice versa :-)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on application for jokes and I have one feature still missing which is showing jokes text view on the same way of showing photos in Iphone, one by one, and having the user slide the finger from right to left, or vice versa :

Does anyone has an example or knows of one?

Comment: use gestures for getting like that.

Comment: Try googling: "use swipe gesture recognizer in iphone"

Comment: I am looking for DVSlideViewController

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `UIPageViewController` if I'm understanding what you're asking.

Setting up a `UIPageViewController` is pretty easy.

```
UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
```

Then simply set the delegate, and create the respective delegate methods, and you're all set!

delegate methods can be referenced from `UIPageViewController`'s [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Good luck! And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I am looking for DVSlideViewController, would you please check this link http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dvslideviewcontroller

Comment: Yeah, you don't even need that library. `UIPageViewController` will give you the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for detecting swipes:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
```

// Add it to the view you want

```
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
```

//the handler code:

```
- (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
     //do something when swiped left.
}
else  if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) 
  {
   //do something when swiped right.
  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for DVSlideViewController, would you please check this link http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dvslideviewcontroller

Comment: Yeah I saw it, similar to UIPageControl only, please note that it is BSD licensed.